# c++ cin.getline() fail

Tags: c++, console-application

my problem is that my program doesnt read the values that I enter by keyboard, only reads the 1st, the 2nd and last. I´ve tried with cin.ignore(); and other solutions but doesn work.

This is the input:

```
Insurance 1
Model: mazda

serial number: 60

Price: 9999

Contract number: 76Z

Contract money: 12
```

//after all characters, there was an \n enter.

This is the output:

```
Insurance 1
Model: mazda

serial number: 60

Price: 0

Contract number: 

Contract money: 12
```

I write here only a function, not all the program:

```
struct tseg{
  char model[15]; //nombre del modelo
  char serialnumber[15]; //número de serie del coche
  double price; //precio de compra del coche
  char contractnumber[15]; //numero del seguro
  double contractmoney; //importe del contrato
};

bool registrarSeguro(tconces *a, int p, int total){ //p is the position!!!

      a[p].contrato = new tseg[a[p].numSegurosActuales];

      cout << "Enter model: " <<endl;
        cin.ignore();
      cin.getline(a[p].contrato[a[p].numSegurosActuales].model, 15);
      cout << "Enter serial number: " <<endl;
        cin.ignore();
      cin.getline(a[p].contrato[a[p].numSegurosActuales].serialnumber, 15);
      cout << "Enter price: " <<endl;
        cin.ignore();
      cin >> a[p].contrato[a[p].numSegurosActuales].price;
      cout << "Enter contract number: " <<endl;
        cin.ignore();
      cin.getline(a[p].contrato[a[p].numSegurosActuales].numContrato, 15);
      cout << "Enter contract number: " <<endl;
      cin >> a[p].contrato[a[p].numSegurosActuales].impContrato;

      a[p].numSegurosActuales++;
      sw = true;

 return (sw);
}
```

Comment: As someone who also speaks English as a second language, I urge you to start coding in English. It will make it that much easier to ask for help on sites like StackOverlow (assuming that your code is self-documenting).

Comment: It would help to know exactly (verbatim) what your input was from the keyboard, and what of that input actually ended up recorded in what parts of your data structure, including things like newline characters.  It might also have been nice to elide the portions of your source code that have nothing to do with the problem (like the first few lines of your function, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use std::getline() in order to read the data into a string, and then copy the contents into your fields, limiting, if needed, the number of characters to copy.

```
#include <util>
#include <cstring>

// ...

std::string input;
std::getline( cin, input );

// +1 char for end of string
std::strncpy( a[p].contrato[a[p].numSegurosActuales].model, input.c_str(), 14 );
```

This way, your inputs will always happen without glitches. No pending characters, no stream errors, no problems at all. The downside is that you'll have to convert numbers if you need them, but you're already doing that. ¡Buena suerte!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with the code. One is that the fields you show for the input, Contrato, is not the ones in the struct. What fields do you use when displaying the values?

The other thing is about cin.ignore(), which by default ignores the next character from the input. It might work for skipping the end-of-line, if you are sure that you are **exactly** at that position. If there might be anything else, like a space or two, you can use cin.ignore(1000, '\n') which skips up to 1000 characters while looking for the end of line.

If you use getline() it reads the entire line, including the end marker, so there you shouldn't use ignore().